# Need to change JSON property using a variable

Tags: javascript, json

```
c.key = "test";
a = {};
a.body = {};
a.body.interval={}; 
a.body.interval = c.key;

b = {};
b.body = {};
b.body.interval={}; 
b.body.interval = c.key;  

c["key"]="sample";

return JSON.stringify(a);
```

I want to change all the values which are referred by mentioned variable in javascript.

Currently, this print

`{"body":{"interval":"test"}}`

I want to change properties referred by `c.key`.
I can not change individual properties of JSON as those are not fixed.

How can I change all the properties referred by an individual variable in javascript?

Comment: You can't determine at runtime whether a variable is actually a reference to another variable(or property/key in your case). What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I have to set different properties after some time when I get the actual value. Those different properties share the same value, so I want to set them later when I have the value

Comment: You need an identification mechanism on each key you want to update. Then just explicitly update those fields when your actual value arrives

Comment: I do not want to individual update on the field, that is the reason I need some pass by reference mechanism which changes the underlying properties

Comment: What do you understand the meaning of  "change a JSON property" to be? A JSON _string_ is a snapshot, in JavvaScript Object Notation format, of some properties of an object.  Just use the object if it's properties are changing.

Comment: @Traktor53 Can you give an example or a reference? I am not able to understand

Comment: MDN ref: [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) where "JSON" is the syntax (format ) used within data strings .  Properties that are methods (function object values) are ignored and not  represented in JSON strings produduced by `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but using a function instead of a variable can solve your problem. (since you can pass a replace function to stringify.

take a look at the following code:

```
c = {};
c.key = "test"

a = {};
a.body = {};
a.body.interval = function(){return c.key};

c["key"]="sample";

JSON.stringify(a, function (key, value) {
        if (key == 'interval') {
            return value();
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    });
```

```js
c = {};
c.key = "test"

a = {};
a.body = {};
a.body.interval = function(){return c.key};

c["key"]="sample";

out = JSON.stringify(a, function (key, value) {
        if (key == 'interval') {
            return value();
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    });
    
console.log(out);
```